# Formating TableViewCell in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I got an app with a table, where i should place a lot of information.

Like this:

[image]

But in the standrad TableViewCell i got only the textLabel and the detailTextLabel. How can i formate information?

First of all im interesting in a text formating.

How can i create a label with a constant width in a TableViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own subviews to the table view cell's `contentView`.  This is explained in [*Table View Programming Guide for iOS*: “Customizing Cells”](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18).

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a custom UITableViewCell.

Apple has provided a [sample project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Listings/5_CustomTableViewCell_Classes_CustomTableViewCellAppDelegate_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318-5_CustomTableViewCell_Classes_CustomTableViewCellAppDelegate_h-DontLinkElementID_33) on custom UITableViewCell.